# Is there a single word that means "under the table"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that means "under the table"?  I am looking for a single word that conveys a knowing, sly, violation of law or ethics — like an *under-the-table* or *off-the-books* payment.

Comment: Do you mean a metaphorical sense of some surreptitious, less-than-savory event transpiring between parties? Or literally underneath the a piece of furniture?

Comment: Do you mean apart _underthetable_?

Comment: I am looking for a single word that conveys a knowing, sly, violation of law or ethics --- like an under-the-table or off-the-books payment.

Comment: Maybe you use the adjective black, like in black market. In German black-money is widely used for illegally earned money.

Comment: Footnotes - often found "under the table".

Comment: subtabular   .......

Answer (score 11):

If you're looking for something that is not known about to others, then  *surreptitiously*.

Answer (score 11):

Three possible adjectives are *illicit*, *illegal* and *underhanded*.

Comment: underhanded is the one I'd use

Comment: @Matt Эллен - Wouldn't that depend on the precise context? In general, I would use _underhand_ (not 'underhanded', which is a non-standard usage) where the emphasis is on the deviousness of an unethical act, _illegal_ for something prohibited by law, and _illicit_ where it is implied that there is something  both illegal and of questionable morality.

Answer (score 7):

[clandestine](http://www.wordnik.com/words/clandestine)

> –adjective
>   Kept or done in secret, often in order to conceal an illicit or improper purpose.

Answer (score 6):

> **covert** - Not openly practiced, avowed, engaged in, accumulated, or shown.
>   [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/covert)

Answer (score 5):

**[Sub rosa](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sub_rosa/)**, sometimes spelled "sub-rosa", means "under the table". It is a borrowed word, from Latin, but used in English language newspapers and elsewhere. It may be used as an adverb or an adjective. Synonyms are **[covertly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikisaurus%3acovert)** and "behind the scenes".

A more informal term for "under the table" is **[downlow](http://down-low.urbanup.com/1340002)** or **[on the down-low](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/on_the_down-low)**.

Answer (score 3):

In italian, for example, we have the one below (of course, the English version, which exists as well):

> **under the counter** (or **table**) - (with reference to goods bought or sold) surreptitiously and typically illegally: *certain labs have been peddling this drug under the counter.*  -|-  [**as adj.**] *an under-the-counter deal*.

Comment: OT - Are you referring to "lavoro nero"?  I seem to remember such a term.

Comment: @gbutters: That expression is correct but the italian corresponding for "under the counter" is "sottobanco". (sotto = under / banco = desk) :)

Comment: In Italian the word "furbo" meaning crafty, is very often used to express anyone who wilfully and knowingly doesn't respect the law, especially those concerning the payment of taxes. Within the word, resides a sense of sneaky admiration, envy, and fierce outrage all rolled in one.

Answer (score 2):

[off-balance-sheet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-balance-sheet)

> Some companies may have significant
>   amounts of off-balance sheet assets
>   and liabilities. For example,
>   financial institutions often offer
>   asset management or brokerage services
>   to their clients. The assets in
>   question (often securities) usually
>   belong to the individual clients
>   directly or in trust, while the
>   company may provide management,
>   depository or other services to the
>   client. The company itself has no
>   direct claim to the assets, and
>   usually has some basic fiduciary
>   duties with respect to the client.
>   Financial institutions may report
>   off-balance sheet items in their
>   accounting statements formally, and
>   may also refer to "assets under
>   management," a figure that may include
>   on and off-balance sheet items.

Answer (score 1):

Mitch's answer is pretty good but the wrong part of speech. You want *surreptitious*.

A less formal (and thus possibly more appropriate depending on your use) term would be *shady*.

Comment: This was months ago so I guess I no longer care, but what was the downvote for?